# TypeScript definition. Can I make number[] something more obvious?

Tags: typescript

In the definition file I am creating, I have a geometric point. It contains an X and Y value and is expressed as a number[].

number[0,0]

As a result, I have hundreds of number[] types. This is not very obvious. Especially when later, a bigger project has to work with its own "Point" class and are exposed to a number[].

Is there any way I can improve this situation.  To somehow replace my number[] types with a more understandable vec2d type even though this is not a part of the original JS library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in many ways, here is an example class that stores the x and y co-ordinates and has a method to represent the point as an array:

```
class Point {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) {

    }

    toPointArray() {
        return [this.x, this.y];
    }
}

var point = new Point(20, 50);
var forLib = point.toPointArray();
```

Comment: Thanks as always Steve!